# javax Bean Validation based on variables?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Let's say I have a class with two member variables:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
class Foo {
    private int minimumAge;
    private int maximumAge;
}
```

I know I can validate minimum / maximum values like this:

```
@Min(1)
private int minimumAge;

@Max(99)
private int maximumAge;
```

But what I really want to do, is to ensure that minimumAge is always less than or equal to maximumAge.  So I want something like this:

```
@Min(1)
@Max(maximumAge)
private int minimumAge;

@Min(minumumAge)
@Max(99)
private int maximumAge;
```

But this does not seem possible with this validation framework, since it only can take constant expressions.  Is there a way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zack said you could use a custom constraint.

With Hibernate Validator you could alternatively work with the [@ScriptAssert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.html) constraint which allows to define constraints using any JSR 223 compatible scripting engine:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.minimumAge < _this.maximumAge")
public class MyBean {

  @Min(1)
  private int minimumAge;

  @Max(99)
  private int maximumAge;

}
```

If you really need to declare constraints in a dynamic way you could use Hibernate Validator's [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#programmaticapi) for programmatic constraint definition:

```
int dynamicallyCalculatedConstraintValue = ...;

ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
mapping.type( MyBean.class )
  .property( "mininumAge", FIELD )
    .constraint( new MaxDef().value( dynamicallyCalculatedConstraintValue ) );

HibernateValidatorConfiguration config = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class ).configure();
config.addMapping( mapping );
Validator validator = config.buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

Comment: I like the @ScriptAssert approach, as it's a simple, straightforward way to define the constraints, without having to implement custom constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have to create a custom constraint.

[http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29) has a good section on creating (or overloading) constraints - "Customized constraints and validators"

Answer (score -1):

This is also something a friend told me, which I think may be even simpler than the @ScriptAssert approach:

`@AssertTrue
  public boolean isValidAge() {
    return minAge < maxAge;
  }`