# What's the drawback if I use OVal instead of JSR-303 validation?

Tags: spring-mvc, playframework, bean-validation, oval

Coming from play 1.x. I like the possibilities of [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/). How ever actual I'm evaluating to setup a stack with Spring MVC. There the default for validation is JSR-303. One problem I see with JSR-303 is to get the context of a property or adjust the message. See [JSR303 Validation - Bean's property as Message Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370419/jsr303-validation-beans-property-as-message-parameter) and [javax Bean Validation based on variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682246/javax-bean-validation-based-on-variables?rq=1). One problem I have in converting a constraint, that checks if the text a user entered only contains valid variables. So the use can add "The member ${name} does an excellent job." If he wrote "The member ${nmae} does an excellent job." he should get a message like: "Your text contains the invalid variable >nmae<, you can only use >name, firstname<".

With Oval this can easily be done. So I wonder if there are disadvantages to use OVal instead of JSR-303.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think it is a good idea to stick to a standard. This ensures portable applications and by using a standard you are using something many developers are familiar with. You are right that your particular use case it not supported atm by Bean Validation. However, Bean Validation 1.1 is on its way and interpolating the validated value is on the roadmap - see [BVAL-219](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-219).
In the meantime you can use Hibernate Validator's [ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/messageinterpolation/ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator.java). Yes you are using a custom extension of Bean Validation, but only for this specific feature.